# Como evitar carregar um favicon?

Tags: html, favicon

Tenho um site em wordpress, o problema é que ele puxa o favicon do site em algum lugar que não consigo achar, verifiquei em todos os arquivos do site e não encontrei nada escrito favicon, quero retirar esse puxamento do código html favicon no código por que ele ta me dando 400 ms a mais de carregamento.

Alguém sabe onde posso achar esse puxamento dele usando alguma ferramenta? já usei essa do google chrome e não consigo achar,inspecionei elemento e não encontrei nada também.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Achei no wordpress includes/load.php a função referente a geração do favicon:

```
function wp_favicon_request() {
    if ( '/favicon.ico' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) {
        header( 'Content-Type: image/vnd.microsoft.icon' );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Alguém sabe onde o wordpress puxa essa função no wordpress?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se não há nada na página que realmente requisite o "favicon", seu browser vai acabar requisitando um "por conta própria", o que não vai resolver o problema.

Uma maneira de evitar este comportamento (que não é garantida que funcione sempre e em todos os browsers) é fornecer um "fake favicon" desta forma, dentro do `<head>`:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/x-icon;," type="image/x-icon">
```

A mesma técnica pode ser usada para "embutir" algum ícone na própria página, mas aí pode ser mais custoso ainda, pois não será "cacheado" e terá custo em toda requisição.

O melhor mesmo seria fornecer de fato um favicon, mas com cabeçalhos de cache para que ele seja armazenado no browser no primeiro acesso, e fique por lá por no mínimo alguns dias, já que é algo que não se sai trocando a todo momento.

Se quiser um GIF transparente, em vez de um ícone inválido, segue o `data-url`:

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon"
  href="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAA///wAAACH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAICRAEAOw=="
  type="image/gif">
```

Sobre a função do WP mencionada, ela não requisita o favicon, ela é acionada caso seja solicitado um. Nesse caso, a tag acima deve evitar inclusive que a função seja chamada.

Comment: Funcionou, o favicon não está mais sendo chamado no meu site, nem aparece no network, minha pontuação no gtmetrix ficou A 100% . valeu

Comment: Que bom que deu certo. Mas lembre-se, mais importante que a pontuação, é a experiência do usuário. Considere a possibilidade de por um favicon de verdade e fazer ele ficar no cache.